# Play a .pls playlist using AVPlayer

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, playlist

I am trying to play a .pls audio stream on the iOS device but it does not seem to be working, this is what I am currently doing;

```
@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mypls.pls"]];   


}
- (IBAction)pushStart:(id)sender {
        [player play];
}
```

Comment: Pls isnt an audio stream, it's a descriptor for a playlist. You need to extract the FileX keys because it [isnt a supported AVPlayer format](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW9)

Comment: That is the whole problem. Not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a .pls stream you actually simply open a playlist with the IP to the stream.
You have to use this IP instead of the .pls file in your code, so instead of linking to the .pls file you link to the stream in the URL field.

Comment: Can you please explain how we can use IP instead of .pls ?